# Hide QueryString with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to hide the querystring part of my links **localhost/out.php?url=http://www.foo.bar**

Making the URL look: **localhost/out.php**

My apache mod_rewrite module is enabled and working.

I've read some other answers and tried a bunch of rewritecond and rewriterules but I can't make it work properly, could someone help me then ?. :$ ty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7841467/106261

Comment: possible duplicate of [trim query string(s) from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669755/trim-query-strings-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/out.php /out.php?
```

from [here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString#Modifying_the_Query_String)

Comment: Tried it but I'm still getting localhost/out.php?url=value :$ Ah, missed to say that mod_rewride module is configured and working in my apache server.