# Use mod_rewrite to remove parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use mod_rewrite to remove a specifik query parameter from an URL.

Example: 
1) User enters URL:

```
http://localhost/intra/page.htm?var1=123&var2=456&var3=789
```

2) mod_rewrite removes "var2=456"

3) New URL:

```
http://localhost/intra/page.htm?var1=123&var3=789
```

My problem is, that I only know the parameter name (var2), and not the value (456), 
and that I newer know the order of the parameters. It might be placed at the beginning as well as the end of the query string.

I would appreciate any help, as I used a lot of time searching the web, without finding any working solution.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756688/mod-rewrite-remove-a-get-variable

Comment: Where does this parameter come from, and why can't you just leave it there when it's not being used at all?

Answer (score 12):

**Its a tricky problem since `var2=anything` can really appear anywhere in query string.**

This code should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&|)var2=[^&]*(?:&(.*)|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why do you need (.+?&|), wouldn't just (.*&|) suffice?  Doesn't .* = .+? essentially, or am I missing something here.  In fact, couldn't it be just (.*)

Comment: Yes you are right. I wrote this answer many years back. I would have written it differently if written now :)

Comment: Ah ok thanks, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.